# Search Google Geocoding API by Neighborhood?

Tags: google-geocoding-api

Oftentimes, when users are searching businesses by specific location, they might unknowingly input a neighborhood name into the search box thinking that it's a city, but since legally it's just a neighborhood Google API will map it to the actual city center. The problem is that in large cities the two locations (neighborhood center and city center) can be quite a distance apart. For example, if I search **Porter Ranch, CA**, Google API returns **Los Angeles, CA**, but the two locations (based on latitude/longitude calculations) are about 23 miles apart, and clearly not what the user intended to see.

Interestingly enough, Google Maps knows Porter Ranch, and if I search "Porter Ranch" it does zoom in on Porter Ranch. And also, if I search a specific address in Porter Ranch, the result is listed as say 123 Main St, Porter Ranch, CA, not as Los Angeles, CA.

So my question is, is there a way to tell Google API to return latitude/longitude of the ***neighborhood***, such as Porter Ranch, instead of the city? I'm hoping there's a way to do this with the API since it works in Maps.

EDIT:

Java example:

```
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext().setApiKey("xyz");
results = GeoCodingApi.geocode(context, "Porter Ranch, CA").await;
```

Comment: Please post examples of your requests. This might help others to understand your issue better and try to find a workaround.

Comment: @xomena i'm not sure how an example would help, geocode api is just one line of code. nevertheless, i updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I execute a geocoding request for 'Porter Ranch, CA' I can see that the coordinate from the response (34.2822134,-118.5506158) is well centered on this neighborhood.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Porter%20Ranch%2C%20CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Have a look at my screenshot

[image]

or check it yourself in the Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DPorter%2520Ranch%252C%2520CA

So, I cannot see any issue with position of marker, however, indeed the formatted address doesn't include the name of neighborhood.

The unique workaround I can think of is executing a reverse geocoding with type neighborhood and coordinate from the first request:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=34.2822134%2C-118.5506158&result_type=neighborhood&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

In this case you will get a name of neighborhood in the formatted address string as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: xomena, you're right, it does return the correct coordinates now. i don't think it was back in june when i posted the question. but you're right, reverse geocoding should solve my other issue of getting the correct location name. i'll give it a try in week after i'm back from vacation, but i think it'll work. thanks!!!